# Kendo Angular 2 grids pager and top header don't expand width with scrolling

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

We have added the horizontal scrolling option via CSS (kendo-grid {overflow: auto;}) to the grids. But, the pager and top header of the grids don't expand their width with scrolling.

Please see the screenshot;

[image: Please see the screenshot]
Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use overflow:auto, but use Kendo UI Grid Scrollable Mode. See docs: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/scroll-modes/#toc-scrollable. I've recently worked with Kendo UI Grid for Angular and that's what I used to have the grid properly scrolled on smaller screens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the Kendo Scrollable Modes for vertical scrolling only. We are looking for horizontal scrolling solution.

Comment: I've used it not far ago in one project and here you can see it adds horizontal scroll as well. http://snpy.in/TEbUNT

Comment: I also do have [width] set to most of my columns, so they never had a chance to fit into provided grid width. Maybe setting column width will make horizontal scroll appear in your case.